# Need to run my app before the unlock screen in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to run my app as the user clicks on the unlock screen. I have used ACTION_USER_PRESENT Intent in a BroadcastReceiver to check. I used the following code. I need to show my app before the unlock screen. But my app is visible after I unlock the screen. Any help will be appreciated.

**My BroadcastReceiver**

```
package com.progressindicator;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {

                Intent s = new Intent(context, ProgressIndicator.class);
                s.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                // s.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

                s.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                s.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.startActivity(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.progressindicator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.progressindicator.ProgressIndicator"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Receive" >
            <intent-filter
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My Activity:**

```
package com.progressindicator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ProgressIndicator extends Activity {
    ImageView loading;
    AnimationDrawable loadAnimation;
    private Window wind;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress_indicator);
    //  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //  requestWindowFeature(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
//      wind = this.getWindow();
//      wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
//      wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
//      wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        getWindow().addFlags(

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED 

            );
        LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
        main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setContentView(main);

        loading = new ImageView(this);
        loading.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
        loadAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)loading.getDrawable();
        main.addView(loading);
    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){

    loadAnimation.start();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.progress_indicator, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible, as showing something that's usable before the user unlocks the screen would open a hell hole for malicious software IMO. You'd be exploting one big security gap if you could do what you want to do.

Comment: But how "Unlock your brain" app available in market did this. please check that app.

Comment: @Manikandan Have you found any solution.Please reply.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @ jagdish, I didn't find a solution and drop that app.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED for your activity to be started, this will temporarily disable keyguard/keylock as long as your activity is on top of all other windows.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for a project some time ago

```
// set flags for staying on and lockscreen
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
       | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

Also I would check your Intent parameters to make sure your creating a new Activity and onCreate is called.

If you want to disable the lock screen, you will need to be a Device Administrator.

EDIT:

ACTION_USER_PRESENT is sent after the user unlocks the screen, that's why it doesn't works for showing a screen on top of the lockscreen.

You should change to ACTION_SCREEN_ON.

Edit 2:
On the manifest I have `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and in the intent I call the activity with:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: @ Nininho I changed my receiver to check for ACTION_SCREEN_ON. But still the same happens. unlock screen stays. did this works for you?

Comment: of course not, if you are't using properly, I wrote my code, but you are closed mind to understand it

Comment: I didn't use the receiver. The app I did was different, I started the app and then on click of a button I would lock the device and start the Activity to show on lockscreen,

Comment: I can't share because it's property of my company, but the code handling the show on lockscreen is these snipets I shared with you. See my new edit for more info and also make sure you only show one Activity on top of lockscreen, if you try to call another Activity it will not open on top.

Comment: @nininho, Have you tested your application if pattern or pin lock enabled? Is your application shown before the pattern or pin lock(if present).

Comment: Yes, it appears before the pattern lock and when the user press back or home the pattern screen appears

Comment: @nininho, Can you please give me any clue or share the idea?

Comment: The idea is the same as the answer, you just have an activity with the flag FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED and start it when the user is on the pattern lock

Comment: @nininho, Thanks, I am doing the same type of app, by your suggestion now my app shows before the pattern and if we do action on the app it directly goes to device home page instead of pattern. How to show the pattern after my application. please help me.

Comment: From my tests it always went to lock unless it was the simple slide lock, the others that have password and pattern all went to lock instead of homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` to your
window flags, as in `Activity.getWindow().addFlags(...)`.
I recommend to use this in addition with `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` and call 
it in your onCreate lifecycle method.

To the "security hole" topic. It is correct that as an app developer you are
able to pop up before the security lockscreen appears, but a simple
home button tap will pause your activity (even a System-Alert) and show the
secure guard.

I know that there are some hacky ways around this, but they do not work 
with every device, are somewhat broken on HTC and Samsumg and no app should
be able to lock out the user.

Steve